# Gradle build using VSTS/TFS: how add the “Gradle task” from the list of templates?

Tags: android, windows, tfs

I need to deploy the server to build the apk file for android.
[link](https://srivatsamarichi.wordpress.com/2016/08/28/gradle-build-using-vststfs/)

I found the instruction inthe network, but I do not understand how to call the *template selection window*.
 The version of server is:
**Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
Версия 14.102.25423.0**
How do I display this template selection window?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using TFS 2015 Update3 (`14.102.25423.0`).

You need to [create a build definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/ci-cd-part-1#create-a-build-definition), then add build steps for the definition.

To call the template selection:

Go to **Build** --> **Create New build definition** (or edit existing build defintion) --> **Select a template** (Based on your projects requirements) --> Set **Repository** and **Default agent queue** then click **Create** --> **Add build Step ...** --> Select **Build** --> Scroll the slider to display the **Gradle** task  --> **Add**

[image]